# Configuring IIS on Windows Vista Home Edition

Tags: iis, windows-vista

My friend accidentally bought a laptop with Windows Vista Home Basic Edition. He figured out how to install IIS on it, but it doesn't seem to have either the management console or the admin tools. Is there any way for him to configure a site or import an IIS 6 config file?

EDIT: "Windows Vista Home Edition" --> "Windows Vista Home Basic Edition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely certain here, but start the IIS console on another machine and tell it to connect to the laptop? The normal management console snap-ins all support remote operation.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I had never noticed the IIS management console can connect to remote machines.

Answer (score 1):

Yu need to go back into Windows Component Setup and choose to install the Managemnet console(s).

Control Panel>Programs->Turn Windows Feature on and off.

You will see Internet Information Services in there, go under there and you will find the management console(s).

And yes, they are available to be installed on Vista Home. Once installed you can setup by opening Control Panel->Adminstrative Tools and you will see the IIS manager in there.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753198.aspx), IIS Management Console is unavailable on Windows Vista Home Basic and Starter Editions though it is available on Home Premium and above. And I can confirm it doesn't appear in the list of options when I install IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not being on Vista I don't know for sure, but on XP the application which controls IIS is `%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\iis.msc`. Perhaps hunting around for `iis.msc` would be a first step.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do an upgrade to home premium. I'm pretty sure it's available at quite a low cost. My Home Basic laptop came with a CD that had all the necessary stuff for upgrading to a different version of Windows (I upgraded to Linux). If you really want IIS to do development work, you should really upgrade.  Or if you just want .Net, you can install VS.Net Express and use the development server.